# Who do I get an ImportError: No module named bootstrap_paginationprofiles

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install a third-party lib to my django app - [django-bootstrap-pagination](https://github.com/jmcclell/django-bootstrap-pagination). However, when I do `python manage.py migrate` Django throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 13, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\client\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\client\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 324, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\client\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\client\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\David\Envs\client\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named bootstrap_paginationprofiles
```

Since it said that the error was located in an **init**.py-file I here is the code of my "profiles"-directory **init**.py-file:

```
default_app_config = "profiles.apps.ProfileConfig"
```

INSTALLED_APPS look like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django_admin_bootstrapped',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'authtools',
    'crispy_forms',
    'easy_thumbnails',
    'geoposition',
    'bootstrap_pagination'

    'profiles',
    'accounts',
    'clients',

)
```

What do I do?

Comment: Have you installed the module with PIP?

Comment: you miss 1 comma after `'bootstrap_pagination'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have in your `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
'bootstrap_pagination'
'profiles',
```

You have a missing comma after `'bootstrap_pagination'` - so it's adding the next one too. So it's becoming - `bootstrap_paginationprofiles` as a result.

To fix it, add the missing comma:

```
'bootstrap_pagination',
'profiles',
```